# Pointer to void*, And generic BUBBLE SORT

Tags: c, sorting, generics, void-pointers

I found this code, in my lecture files.
This is a generic function that gets a compare function and array, and sort it with BUBBLE SORT

```
typedef Relation (*CmpFunction)(void*, void*);
void sort(void **array, int n, CmpFunction compare){ 
   int i, j;
   void*  tmp;
   assert(array !=NULL && compare != NULL);
   for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
      for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
         if(compare(arr[i], arr[j])==Left) {
            tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Relation is: ENUM Type(Not interesting).
My Question is, Why sort() get

> void**,

Why isn't it

> void*

.
P.S The writer of the lecture did it on purpose, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: check this link: [A somewhat generic implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/Bubble_sort_%28C%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a generic sort, it's a sorter for arrays of `void *`.

Thus, the `array` is `void **`, meaning "pointer to pointer to `void *`". You can dereference it once, `array[0]` is the first `void *` to be sorted. Of course you can't dereference *that* though, since `void *` doesn't support that.

By the way, the standard library's `qsort()` is a better example of a generic sort.

Comment: So if i pass an array of ints, then the function will cast the array to void** and every element will be casted to void*?

Comment: Yes, so don't do that since you can't assume that `sizeof (int) == sizeof (void *)`. It's intended to sort arrays of `void` pointers.